# Angular PWA - caching remote image(s)

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I am trying to cache images using an Angular 7 PWA app (created via `ng add @angular/pwa`). Everything works perfectly except for the images. This is how the `ngsw-config.json` file looks like (at least the appropriate section):

```
{
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
          "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**",
          "https://res.cloudinary.com/**"
        ]
      }
    }
```

What's strange is that when I take a look at the cache using DevTools I see the images in there (along with the fonts). But when I take the application offline, it's only the images that do not work - they basically come back with a 504 error:

`Error: Response not Ok (fetchAndCacheOnce): request for https://res.cloudinary.com/[removed]/image/upload/[removed].png returned response 504 Gateway Timeout` (I have removed parts of the URL)

The fonts, however return an `HTTP 200` (from the Service Worker).

I'm quite baffled over this, why wouldn't the images be served in offline mode? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - it turns out that when using Cloudinary images, with the `f_auto` flag, Cloudinary returns a `Vary` HTTP header, which causes some issues. At the moment I haven't found a way to set the `ingoreVary` option for Cache API via `ngsw`. More info here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28443#issuecomment-490765336